# I want to scale a 3D object so that it always appeats to be the same size, no matter how far from the camera

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, graphics, scaling

I have the world, view, and projection matrices.  I have an object that is part of the UI and should be the same size no matter how far from the camera it is.  I'm using this to create a gizmo similar to the "move" gizmos you see in 3D modelling program.

How can I extract a proper scale to do this from world/view/projection (or from the view frustrum if preferred, I have the six planes).

Bonus question: Using these same matrices, is there a decent way to figure out how much I'd need to move a 3D vector to make it move ONE PIXEL visually?

Comment: Skip the world matrix. Your object should use the camera's transform as its parent.